# How get to acccess XML Elements in After Effects after importing data?

Tags: javascript, xml, after-effects

I posted something similar to this earlier today using JSon, but giving up on that I've switched to XML. Can someone show me what I am doing wrong here? I have an xml file that I am parsing through a script in After Effects, and I'm not sure how to get access to the XML elements.

My XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <f>
        <accelX>0.4682</accelX>
        <accelY>-0.0352</accelY>
        <accelZ>-0.9247</accelZ>
        <gyroX>0.0555</gyroX>
        <gyroY>0.004</gyroY>
        <gyroZ>-0.0684</gyroZ>
    </f>
    <f>
        <accelX>-0.4682</accelX>
        <accelY>-0.0219</accelY>
        <accelZ>-0.9186</accelZ>
        <gyroX>0.0049</gyroX>
        <gyroY>0.0851</gyroY>
        <gyroZ>-0.046</gyroZ>
    </f>
</root>
```

And my jsx file is this:

```
var file = new File;
var check = 0;

var mainWindow = new Window("palette", "File Reader", undefined);
mainWindow.orientatizzaaq1on = "column";

var groupOne = mainWindow.add("group", undefined, "groupOne");
groupOne.orientation = "row";
var fileLocBox = groupOne.add("edittext", undefined, "Selected File Location");
fileLocBox.size = [150, 20];
var getFileButton = groupOne.add("button", undefined, "File...");
getFileButton.helpTip = "Select a .json file to change the comp";

var groupTwo = mainWindow.add("group", undefined, "groupTwo");
groupTwo.orientation = "row";
var applyButton = groupTwo.add("button", undefined, "Apply");

mainWindow.center();
mainWindow.show();

getFileButton.onClick = function() {
    file = file.openDlg("Open a file", "Acceptable Files:*.xml");
    fileLocBox.text = file.fsName;
    check = 1;
    }

applyButton.onClick = function() {
        if(check == 0) {
                alert("Please select a file");
                return false;
            } else {
                //app.beginUndoGroup("Comp Changes");
                var fileExtension = fileLocBox.text;
                var fileData;
                
                if(fileExtension.substring(fileExtension.length-4, fileExtension.length) == "json") {
                    fileData = readJson();
                    } else {
                        switch(fileExtension.substring(fileExtension.length-3, fileExtension.length)) {
                            case "txt":
                                //fileData = readTxt();
                            break;
                            case "xml":
                                fileData = readXml();
                            break;
                            }
                        }
                    changeComp(fileData);
                }
            alert("done");
   }

function readXml() {
    file.open("r");
    var xmlString = file.read();
    var myXml = new XML(xmlString);
    file.close();
    return myXml;
    }

function changeComp(data) {
    var nullz = app.project.activeItem.layers.addNull();
    nullz.threeDLayer = true;
    nullz.name = "parent to me";
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
       var temp = data.f[0].accelX;
       var t =i/25;
      nullz.xRotation.setValueAtTime(t, temp);
      }
  }
```

This is the line, near the end, that isn't working:

```
var temp = data.f[0].accelX;
```

Am I writing this incorrectly? After Effects will create one keyframe with a value of "0", but doesn't finish the for...loop and doesn't complete the script.
Am I accessing these elements incorrectly?

Comment: I think you want `f[i]` instead of `f[0]`. `f[0]` is going to get you the same item (the first one) every time through the loop.

Comment: yes, that is true, and I did have that at some point, I think I changed it while trying to troubleshoot; at this point, though, I'd be happy to just get f[0] 20 times in a row... either way its not working.

Comment: I haven’t looked at your code closely yet—i will when i get to a computer in a few minutes.

Comment: looking now. apologies for the delay.

Comment: `laayers` has an extra 'a'?

Comment: ha, yes it does and I noticed/fixed that a few minutes ago, but thats not it, thats a newer error on my part.

Comment: Yeah. I think I've got it working. Posting an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the core issue is that the value of `data.f[0].accelX` comes in as a string, not a number (e.g. `"4.6"` as opposed to `4.6`) so the `setValueAtTime` ends up with a non-numeric value, which doesn't work<sup>1</sup>.

The solution is to use `parseFloat` on it:

```js
var temp = parseFloat(data.f[0].accelX);
```

With that plus the typo in `laayers` I was able to get it to work. I think. I don't know what it's *supposed* to do, but I end up with a new null layer that has 20 rotation keyframes on x, which feels like progress.

I think there might still be some issues on parenting and naming, but I think the above will get you unstuck and onto the next problem.

Cheers.

---

<sup>1</sup> I think it probably crashes the script and emits an error message somewhere, but I don't really remember how AE scripting works and I don't have ESTK installed (apparently) so I can't open the script editor.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you for taking the time to look into this, it is working, at least in this current state- I wasn't familiar with parseFloat so I can only imagine how long I would've been running around in circles with this. Thank you again.